# (Pytest + Selenium ) Reading data from excel sheet and submitting webpage with radio buttons and drop downs

Tags: selenium, pytest, openpyxl

****`I am working on pytest + selenium for Data driven testing for below page
https://thetestingworld.com/testings/
I have an excel sheet which contains values of all the fields and drop downs.
Each row contains data for each iteration of testing, and column has data for attributes of webpage.
My code is not working and filling up random values on the page.
https://dpaste.org/zmLW
Would appreciate if someone can help me in finding out the issue.
**This is not for any production project, I am learning python and Selenium and got stuck here.
Many thanks in advance.**

Comment: Welcome. Please add your code here, so other people don't need to go to an external site. It's completely fine to have even a bit longer code here, that's why this site exists.

Answer (score 0):

You `data_generator()` doesn't seem to be correct. I'll first copy the whole function here, so it's visible without going to an external site:

```
def dataGenerator():
    data1_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Pycharm/Input File/Data1.xlsx") 
    data1_worksheet = data1_workbook["Sheet1"]   
    data1_rows = data1_worksheet.max_row
    data1_cols = data1_worksheet.max_column​
​
    for i in range(1,data1_rows):
        List1 = []
        for j in range(1,data1_cols+1):
            cell_value = work_sheet.cell(i,j)
            List1.append(cell_value.value)
        Final_list.append(List1)
    print(Final_list)
```

You're printing `Final_list`, but you should be returning it: `return Final_list`.

Then your parametrization: `@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', dataGenerator())` doesn't seem correct in a way in which it's used later, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_name("fld_username").send_keys(data)`, but `data` will contain one row from your excel, not only one cell.